# How to calculate the odds ratio of continuous variables transformed by restricted cubic splines in a logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, odds-ratio, cubic

I am trying to incorporate several  non-linear continuous variables into a logistic model, thus, restricted cubic splines(RCS) is used into the model. However,  I don't know how to get the odds ratios and the 95% confidence intervals of these continuous variables transformed by RCS. Some paper reported their established model by showing these two parameters of every variables included. As showed in the last column of the picture, the established model with a variable named TST90SaO2 transformed by RCS was reported.

[image: The last column in the picture described the model with a variable named TST90SaO2 transformed by RCS.]

In R, what I already know is that the `summary()` function will show the interquartile-range odds ratios.Is it possible to calculate the odds ratio by the interquartile-range odds ratios or I have to use other function or ways?

In the code sample, the Affairs dataset was used and I changed the number of affairs into a dichotomize variable and name it as ynaffairs to act as a dependent variable to be predicted by age, years of marriage, religiousness and rating.

```r
fit_aff_rcs <- lrm(formula = ynaffairs ~ rcs(age,4) + 
                   rcs(yearsmarried,3) + religiousness + rating, 
+                  data = Affairs)
> fit_aff_rcs
Logistic Regression Model

lrm(formula = ynaffairs ~ rcs(age, 4) + rcs(yearsmarried, 3) + 
    religiousness + rating, data = Affairs)

                       Model Likelihood      Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                             Ratio Test             Indexes          Indexes    
Obs           601    LR chi2      63.44      R2       0.148    C       0.708    
 0            451    d.f.             7      R2(7,601)0.090    Dxy     0.417    
 1            150    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    R2(7,337.7)0.154    gamma   0.418    
max |deriv| 2e-06                            Brier    0.167    tau-a   0.156    

              Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
Intercept      2.1044 1.9409  1.08  0.2783  
age           -0.0599 0.0812 -0.74  0.4605  
age'           0.4029 0.7428  0.54  0.5875  
age''         -0.9266 1.6473 -0.56  0.5738  
yearsmarried   0.2068 0.0770  2.69  0.0072  
yearsmarried' -0.1739 0.1020 -1.70  0.0883  
religiousness -0.3254 0.0897 -3.63  0.0003  
rating        -0.4581 0.0894 -5.12  <0.0001
```